# Duplicate row of low occurrence in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In the following dataset what's the best way to duplicate row with groupby(['Type']) count < 3 to 3. df is the input, and df1 is my desired outcome. You see row 3 from df was duplicated by 2 times at the end. This is only an example deck. the real data has approximately 20mil lines and 400K unique Types, thus a method that does this efficiently is desired.

```
>>> df
  Type  Val
0    a    1
1    a    2
2    a    3
3    b    1
4    c    3
5    c    2
6    c    1
>>> df1
  Type  Val
0    a    1
1    a    2
2    a    3
3    b    1
4    c    3
5    c    2
6    c    1
7    b    1
8    b    1
```

Thought about using something like the following but do not know the best way to write the func.

```
df.groupby('Type').apply(func)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is append if removed `6    c    1` ? Last value per group `c` ? there is more columns or only 2 ?

Comment: What is the output if the group contains count 2 which value need to duplicate in this case?

Comment: Good question Sandeep, for now let's assume if a group has a count 2, we duplicate both thus ending up with total 4 rows.

Comment: in my real case, the threshold for duplication is around 1000 and those low count group's count can vary from 1-999, idealy I want to duplicate ceil(1000/grpCnt)-1 times then fill the remaining gap to 1000 with randomly sampled from the group.

Comment: @elgnoh You mean say that overall number of duplications cannot be greater than 1000, but each group should contains atleast 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
counts = df.Type.value_counts()
repeat_map = 3 - counts[counts < 3]
df['repeat_num'] = df.Type.map(repeat_map).fillna(0,downcast='infer')
df = df.append(df.set_index('Type')['Val'].repeat(df['repeat_num']).reset_index(), 
               sort=False, ignore_index=True)[['Type','Val']]

print(df)

  Type  Val
0    a    1
1    a    2
2    a    3
3    b    1
4    c    3
5    c    2
6    c    1
7    b    1
8    b    1
```

**Note :** `sort=False` for `append` is present in `pandas>=0.23.0`, remove if using lower version.

**EDIT :** If data contains multiple val columns then make all columns columns as index expcept one column and repeat and then reset_index as:

```
df = df.append(df.set_index(['Type','Val_1','Val_2'])['Val'].repeat(df['repeat_num']).reset_index(), 
               sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Better you use `sort=False` to `sort=True` or vice versa as require rather using lower version

Comment: Thank you for the answer. would this work if my dataset has more than 1 Val column?

Comment: @elgnoh Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.